# boost program options multiple values for an option

Tags: c++, boost, command-line-interface, boost-program-options

When I type `a.out -i file0 file1` at the command line, I want the option `-i` to receive both `file0` and `file1` But, `-i` only receive `file0` but not `file1`

But, I found that I had to type `a.out -i file0 -i file1` to make `-i` option to receive both `file0` and `file1`

Can `boost::program_options` do this?

Code adapted from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/program_options/example/options_description.cpp

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

using namespace boost;
namespace po = boost::program_options;

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

// A helper function to simplify the main part.
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<T>& v)
{
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<T>(os, " "));
    return os;
}

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    try {
        int opt;
        int portnum;
        po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
        desc.add_options()
                ("help", "produce help message")
                ("input-file,i", po::value< vector<std::string> >(), "input "
                        "file")
                ;

        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::command_line_parser(ac, av).
                options(desc).run(), vm);
        po::notify(vm);

        if (vm.count("help")) {
            cout << "Usage: options_description [options]\n";
            cout << desc;
            return 0;
        }


        if (vm.count("input-file"))
        {
            cout << "Input files are: "
                 << vm["input-file"].as< vector<std::string> >() << "\n";
        }

    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Flagging your `value` as [`multitoken`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/typed_value.html#idp908724720-bb) should make it behave as you expect. `("input-file,i", po::value<vector<std::string>>()->multitoken(), "input file")`

Comment: @SeanCline Consider making this an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From Sean Cline:

Flagging your value as multitoken should make it behave as you expect.

```
("input-file,i", po::value<vector<std::string>>()->multitoken(), "input file")
```